# Binding to web services from windows 7 phone

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-phone-7, dynamics-crm-2011

I am making an app for a Windows 7 Phone that I want to connect to Microsoft CRM 2011 via web services.

I previously created a console app and was able to get it to send data without problems. Getting it to work on the phone has been much harder though. After much trouble shooting I found that the problem is within the binding that I have the phone using. It seems that I need a **SymmetricSecurityBindingElement**, which is not available on the windows phone. Is there a way to not require this element or a workaround?

EDIT

Here is my binding for the console app, which works fine.

```
BindingElementCollection bindingElements = new BindingElementCollection();

SymmetricSecurityBindingElement security = new SymmetricSecurityBindingElement();
security.IncludeTimestamp = true;
security.ProtectionTokenParameters = new SspiSecurityTokenParameters();
bindingElements.Add(security);

bindingElements.Add(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap12WSAddressing10, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8));

HttpTransportBindingElement transport = new HttpTransportBindingElement();
transport.MaxBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;
transport.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue;
bindingElements.Add(transport);

CustomBinding binding = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding(bindingElements);
binding.Name = "CustomBinding_IDiscoveryService";
return binding;
```

Here is my binding for the windows phone. It throws a **MessageSecurityException**.

```
BindingElementCollection phoneBindingElements = new BindingElementCollection();

TransportSecurityBindingElement security = new TransportSecurityBindingElement();
security.IncludeTimestamp = true;
phoneBindingElements.Add(security);

phoneBindingElements.Add(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap12WSAddressing10, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8));

HttpTransportBindingElement transport = new HttpTransportBindingElement();
transport.MaxBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;
transport.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue;
phoneBindingElements.Add(transport);

CustomBinding binding = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding(phoneBindingElements);
binding.Name = "CustomBinding_IDiscoveryService";
```

Comment: Post a code sample. Binding web services is generally the same as console apps. You do need to use Asynchronous methods.

Comment: I think wp7 only supports basicHttpBinding binding... can you use this binding?

Comment: When I use a BasicHttpBinding I get a FaultException - "an error occured when verifying security for the message."